# .htaccess makes php files downloadable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, download

I have an .htaccess file with following content:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
```

For some reason, whenever I upload it to the server, Firefox then wants to download PHP files instead of showing them, I think the Apache server has some error. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `AddType` instead of `AddHandler`.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

If it doesn't work, then just delete whole line. Deleting worked for me.